# Populating droplist in ASP.NET with SQL Server takes a long time. Any optimizations?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, optimization

One of my web pages populates a droplist with about 60k items pulled from SQL Server, and this operation takes upwards of 10 seconds to complete. Are there some tricks or optimizations I can try to improve performance? I'm using a SqlDataSource configured as a DataReader.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just wondering, how are 60k items in a drop down list working out usability wise?

Comment: Well, once the page loads, and all the items have been loaded into memory, it works fine.  Until then, it is very choppy.

Comment: Correction.  I'm loading 40k items.

Comment: Do you use your application yourself?  Tried searching through a very (very) large dropdown list for the particular item you want...?

Comment: Also there is probably a non-trivial rendering time on the browser that has to occur - especially with that many items - even more so it the items are returned as some sort of DTO/json and then need to be proccessed client side to add them to the DropDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any operation that gets a large amount of data from the DB will take a while.

Populating a dropdown with that many items will also take some time as will transmission of the resulting html to the browser.

Not to mention that 60k items in a dropdown list is not very usable.

The optimisation is to change your application so it doesn't need 60k items in one go.

Perhaps a paged approach is more appropriate, where you only get a small subset of the data at a time and can display different parts of it.

You can consider an autocomplete as another option.

Comment: I've considered that, but I don't think it would work too well.  What I'm working with is a database containing records of every product we've manufactured.  This particular page allows a user to view product information based on serial number.  The user can either type in the sn if known, or look for it in a drop down list.

Comment: So, they know what they are looking for in a dropdown - can't you use a string as a search term to pick up products?

Comment: @Curtis - why would it not work well to try another approach? You've exceeded the reasonable number of records for presentation in a dropdown. Perhaps list your product inventory by category? Imagine if Amazon listed all of their CDs in a dropdown? It just isn't practical. You need to make your product list available in another way, perhaps via serial number search, product title search, browsed paging, and product categories.

Comment: @Curtis: couldn't you create a little popup view with a filtering capability? E.g. show me all the "widgets" we've ever produced, and then get back a manageable list of products? 40K items in a dropdown seems quite unmanageable to me...

Answer (score 2):

60,000 items is going to be way too much both for performance and from the user's perspective. Try either cascading dropdown (if it makes sense) or an autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you're doing a **SELECT ***

Change the call to the database to a **Stored Procedure** or **View**

Try dumping the result into the **ASP.Net Cache** and check if that's null before querying the database again.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting 60k into a dropdown is not that useful, I would suggest switching to some sort of [auto complete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, I think you should expend some energy pondering the necessity of retrieving 60k records in one shot. Can you not provide some sort of cascading functionality so that only a subset at a time is required? Or perhaps an auto-complete search function? There's got to be a better way. And just think, not only will you improve the database performance, but you'll likely enhance usability in the process!